# SSO between Sharepoint 2013 and another asp.net website using asp.membership provider form authentication

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I have been trying to setup authentication between SharePoint and another asp website. SharePoint has been setup to use FBA membership provider, the same database used by the asp.net website. The problem is how to login to one of them, I would prefer it to be sharepoint and then be able to get to a page in the other without logging in again.

I have tried setting this [link](http://labs.3pillarglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Single-Sign-On-White-paper.pdf), but using sql membership provider, but I don't think this could work as the way auth cookies are used by browsers.

You can't share auth cookies between `site1.something.com` and `site2.something.com`, only `something.com/site1` and `something.com/site2` as I understand it.

I would be happy either way but would prefer to keep them separate in IIS.

Does anyone know if this is possible.